# Empty editable table abap

Tags: abap, alv

I need to display empty editable table in SAP (something like transaction SM30 when you want to insert new records). I know how to make editable table, but my problem is how to display empty table. I true with   `APPEND INITIAL LINE TO t_output` but is not working.

Comment: By "editable table", do you mean an ALV?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my problem
This is my previous code.

```
 DO 5 TIMES.
    APPEND INITIAL LINE TO t_output.
  ENDDO.
t_output_alv = t_output.
     IF go_container IS INITIAL.
    CREATE OBJECT go_container
      EXPORTING
        container_name = 'CONTAINER'.
    CREATE OBJECT go_grid
      EXPORTING
        i_parent = go_container.
    CALL METHOD go_grid->set_table_for_first_display
      EXPORTING
        is_layout            = s_layout
        is_variant           = s_variant
      CHANGING
        it_fieldcatalog      = t_fieldcat
        it_outtab            = t_output_alv.
  ENDIF.
```

and this is my new  code.

```
  DO 5 TIMES.
        APPEND INITIAL LINE TO t_output_alv.
      ENDDO.
```

The difference here is that in the second code i'm appending to `t_output_alv` not to `t_output`.

Comment: This will only be the solution if you have declared `t_output` as table with header line, which is deprecated and should no be done any more. Otherwise the assignment would have taken care of this.

Comment: I'm declaring like
` DATA s_output like vbak . 
DATA t_output like standard table of  s_output.`

Comment: I'd suggest adding that to the question instead of the (basically un-format-able comments).